# Apache CXF SSL through proxy

Tags: ssl, cxf, http-proxy

I am connecting to an external soap endpoint using Apache CXF.  I am going through a proxy server (using credentials) before I hit the https/SSL external endpoint.  The team that supports the external web service is saying that they do not see my basic authentication header.  I logged the header and payload from my workstation before just before it leaves my workstation.  I can see both the basic authentication and the proxy authentication headers.

My question is really twofold:
 1. At what point is the SSL message from my computer actually encrypted?
 2. Is it possible for something in the network to be dropping the Basic authorization header?
 3. What additional troubleshooting steps can I take?

Comment: This is what should happen. 1. your client (workstation) sends a _CONNECT endpoint:443_ request to the proxy, containing (or not) the proxy credentials. 2. the proxy opens a connection to the endpoint. 3. the proxy sends a 200 OK to the client. 4. The client starts an SSL handshake with the endpoint. 5. When the handshake is finished, the client sends the request with the credentials. In conclusion, the proxy never knows what you are requesting and your endpoint credentials, since all this comes after the SSL handshake. We need logs and/or a capture to investigate your problem.

Comment: I can see all of that happening.  I am receiving a 500, after all of that happens.  I can see the handshake working fine, and my message leaving our network after the handshake. But external entity says that they cannot see my basic auth headers, but print it out via an interceptor right before I the network handshake starts.

Comment: Please run your CXF call with `-Djavax.net.debug=all` _system property_. It is verbose, and it will show the request you are sending including the headers. If you have difficulties to read this trace, post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue,  my proxy server was dropping any header with the word Basic in it.

Thanks,
Brian